# crontab: waitpid() failed waiting for PID xxx from "/usr/bin/sensible-editor": No child processes

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I have a problem similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/357180/ubuntu-crontab-e-usr-bin-sensible-editor-killed-signal-9-no-core-dumped): after running `crontab -e` and exiting the editor (`mcedit`), the temp file is *not* saved, and the screen gets filled with a repeating error message:

> crontab: waitpid() failed waiting for PID 3910 from "/usr/bin/sensible-editor": No child processes
>   crontab: waitpid() failed waiting for PID 3910 from "/usr/bin/sensible-editor": No child processes
>   crontab: waitpid() failed waiting for PID 3910 from "/usr/bin/sensible-editor": No child processes
>   ...

`~/.selected_editor` is:

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/mcedit"
```

I've run `select-editor` again just to make sure, but I get the same result. Executing `/usr/bin/sensible-editor` launches `mcedit`. What is crontab's problem?

I've overwritten `/usr/bin/sensible-editor` with a symlink to `/bin/nano`, but I keep getting the same error. This makes it impossible to run `crontab -e`.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/168710/504387